# get current datetime from remote computer python

Tags: python, datetime, remote-access, remote-server

i have a python project of reading data from multiple remote computer`s sql table and local files.
i need to read only new data and avoid duplicates/missing dates, so i filter data by max date from previous read, but got into an issue when remote computer datetime is changed (manually applied on demand).
how can i read remotely the computer current datetime?
i currently connect to remote pc folders using win32net for specific file reading and sqlalchemy for the sql read.

all computers run windows and in same internal network

Comment: Might be worth looking at NTP, this is the standard way of ensuring that all computers agree on what time/date it is in a distributed system.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [vector clock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_clock) which is a fancy way of saying that you maintain the last timestamp you have seen per host, and use the host specific timestamp to see what changed. If datetime on the remote hosts changes back then you cannot use a timestamp.  Any other monotonic increasing id (for instance a primary key) that would work just as well.

If win32net gives you a command line you can use `date /t` on the remote host to get the time.  You didn't say what database you use, but all that I know have a date function so it would natural for you to use.

Yes, networked hosts should be synced via ntp, but that doesn't eliminate the problem just makes the clock skews much smaller.

Comment: Many thanks, i didnt manage to get the computer datetime, i dont have win32net cmd (run os.listdir on folder), i also tried different primary keys instead of date but they were not useabale for timeline. eventually i created a filtration for the existing data by creating a list of all dates for specific pc from last X hours, its not elegant and will fail if pc time changed more then X hours, but its suffice for now