# python datetime.now() of remote server

Tags: python, linux, datetime, remote-server

One server runs Python code to populate a InfluxDB that is running on another server.
At restart of the Python server, I want to check the last timestamp in InfluxDB and compare it with the datetime of the Python server.
Both servers are Linux, none of them is a ntp server.

On the local Python server I can use Python datetime.now(), *but how can I read datetime of the reomote?*
I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66312441/10803300), but was'nt very helpful.

Comment: Just for curiosity, are you sure both servers are going to show you a different time ?

Comment: The only way to read the current time on the remote server is to connect to the remote server and run some code. Maybe `ssh remoteserver date`? Maybe something like [testinfra](https://testinfra.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)? Maybe run some sort of HTTP API on the remote system that would provide that information?

Comment: @MauriceMeyer: to be more exact: i will compare the time of the remote server with the create time of a file on another remote server. Both servers refer to a ntp server but we experienced several issues of not time sync due to 'lost' settings.

Comment: https://docs.influxdata.com/flux/v0/stdlib/universe/now/ can't you just query influxdb for `now()`?

Comment: if your servers run on systemd / have [timesyncd](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/systemd-timesyncd) running, can you make sure they both sync their time with an NTP server? That should already give you decent time sync between the two.

Comment: @erik258. Function now() indeed exists in the Flux language, but I have no idea how to use that in my Python script.    btw: I'm running influxDB v1.8

Comment: managed to have some results:   from influxdb_client import InfluxDBClient  client = InfluxDBClient(url= my_host, token = my_token, org=my_org, database = my_database)  client.api_client.call_api('/ping', 'GET')  (None,
 204,
 HTTPHeaderDict({'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Request-Id': '9851da81-bbbd-11ee-a96d-00155d320807', 'X-Influxdb-Build': 'OSS', 'X-Influxdb-Version': '1.8.10', 'X-Request-Id': '9851da81-bbbd-11ee-a96d-00155d320807', 'Date': 'Thu, 25 Jan 2024 20:09:07 GMT'}))